# Are there any tools for converting C# Class Libraries to Silverlight Library?

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have written a C# class library (DLL) and wondering the quickest way to make this usable in Silverlight?  Presumably I will have to convert it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference between a .NET class library and a Silverlight class library is that they reference a different set of "core" assemblies, e.g. `mscorlib.dll`, `System.dll`, etc.

- If you have the sources: You can convert the .NET class library to a Silverlight class library simply by starting a new Silverlight Class Library project in Visual Studio and copy&paste all sources. You'd have to fix all API calls that are different in Silverlight, of course.
- If you don't have the sources: I don't know if there's a good way to directly convert the assembly. I doubt you can just replace the references to the .NET assembles with references to Silverlight assemlies. The only way I can think of using .NET Reflector to decompile the assembly and re-compile it as above.

Comment: Re-build from source, and understand that although Silverlight is a subset of the full framework and BCL, it is a *subset* and not everything will work "as is."